# Loops and showConfirmDialog

Tags: java, loops, joptionpane

I'm new to Java, and I need help. I created a game where the program generates a random number (1-100), and the user has to guess it. The game works. The problem I have is that when the user guesses the correct number, I have to ask the player, using showConfirmDialog, if they want to play again then use a loop to either play again or finish. Can anyone show me how to do so? Anything is greatly appreciated.

```
package guessinggame;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Guessinggame {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int guess;
    int numguess = 0;
    int usernum;

    int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, " Do you want to play? ", " Notice ", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

    if (result == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {

        do {
            //game starts here
            guess = (int) (Math.random() * 100 + 1);
            usernum = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("enter your guess"));
            numguess++;

            if (usernum > guess) {
                System.out.println(usernum + " is too high. Try again");
            } else if (usernum < guess) {
                System.out.println(usernum + " is too low. Try again");
            }
        } while (guess != usernum);

        int IQ = ((int) (Math.random() * 100 + 1)) + numguess;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " Correct, it took you " + numguess + " tries. Your IQ is " + IQ);

        //Use showConfirmDialog to if player wants to play again. 
        // If user chooses yes, play game again. If user chooses no end game
    } else if (result == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Quiting? Bye!");
        System.exit(0);
    }

}

}
```

Comment: You have to write that code inside one more do..while, i.e, outer do...while will ask user to play game again and depends on the reply the game will work.

Comment: I would create a separate function playGame() and loop this function instead of the whole code. It would be more readable.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions ill try them both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it by wrapping everything in a while loop infinitely like this:

```
package guessinggame;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Guessinggame {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int guess;
    int numguess = 0;
    int usernum;

  while(true) { //Start of while loop

    int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, " Do you want to play? ", " Notice ", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

    if (result == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {

        do {
            //game starts here
            guess = (int) (Math.random() * 100 + 1);
            usernum = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("enter your guess"));
            numguess++;

            if (usernum > guess) {
                System.out.println(usernum + " is too high. Try again");
            } else if (usernum < guess) {
                System.out.println(usernum + " is too low. Try again");
            }
        } while (guess != usernum);

        int IQ = ((int) (Math.random() * 100 + 1)) + numguess;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, " Correct, it took you " + numguess + " tries. Your IQ is " + IQ);

        //Use showConfirmDialog to if player wants to play again. 
        // If user chooses yes, play game again. If user chooses no end game
    } else if (result == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Quiting? Bye!");
        System.exit(0);
    }

  } //End of While Loop

}

}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! BTW just in case someone wants to use this in the future, move the "guess = (int)(Math.random() * 100 + 1);" out of the do loop, but keep it within the if statement. In easier terms, move that code of line up 3 lines.

Comment: @J.LaGrange can you please accept my answer and upvote it if the solution worked for you?

Comment: @J.LaGrange Thanks !